# Android volley - concurrent/parallel get requests from viewpager fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-volley

I have implemented a viewpager with two fragments each of which send a single GET request to volley. Since these two fragments are loaded at the same time, when using the default request queue in volley I get a single client connection manager error. Here is my request queue code which resides in a singleton:

```
client = new DefaultHttpClient();
mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext(), new HttpClientStack(client));
```

This results in the following error:

```
W/SingleClientConnManager﹕ Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager:connection still allocated. 
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one
```

I switched to using a ThreadedConnectionManager and it seems to have solved the problem. Solution below:

```
DefaultHttpClient mDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

final ClientConnectionManager mClientConnectionManager = mDefaultHttpClient.getConnectionManager();
final HttpParams mHttpParams = mDefaultHttpClient.getParams();
final ThreadSafeClientConnManager mThreadSafeClientConnManager = new  ThreadSafeClientConnManager( mHttpParams, mClientConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry() );

mDefaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient( mThreadSafeClientConnManager, mHttpParams );

final HttpStack httpStack = new HttpClientStack( mDefaultHttpClient );

mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext(),  httpStack);
```

My Question is: Is there a better way of solving this problem or is my solution appropriate? What is the best practice here given my use case?

Comment: Are you making  newRequestQueue every time ? Or it gets created the first time only ?

Comment: It's created only once

Comment: Tried to help. Please see answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem recently, think this would be helpful.

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.shinetechnolab.testmaterial.utils.LruBitmapCache;

public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Then add to RequestQueue.

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest,
                tag_json_arry);
```